# Razer Carcharias Headset not detected in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, headphones

Today I got a shiny new Razer Carcharias Headset for X-Box and PC. When I tried plugging them into my laptop however, Windows seems simply not to detect them. All the lights come on on the headset, and I hear a light static in the background (from what I've read this is a common side-effect of usb connections), but the device simply does not appear under Playback Devices or in the Device Manager. Any sound played comes out of my laptop speakers. When connecting them to the audio jack on the laptop, its the same story except then even the lights don't even come on and I don't think its getting any power at all. I recently had another USB headset plugged in and working fine, I have tried every USB port on the computer, and at this point I really don't know what else I can try. Any suggestions or should I return the headset?

Comment: You have connected the 3.5mm cables yes?

Comment: My guess you don't have drivers for your sound card installed based on dozens of other people question describing the same problem

Comment: I have tried connecting the 3.5mm cables into the jacks yes and it does not seem to work. @Ramhound Another headset I have works perfectly fine on this computer, plus the laptop's speakers work, so I don't see how this could be a problem with the sound card drivers.

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with Razer?

Comment: Is a support ticket just contacting their support? I have not tried to as I only got this headset a couple hours ago and was hoping there might be a simple solution to fix it but I'll contact them now. How long will I usually need to wait for a response?

Comment: How would I know the answer to that question?

Comment: lol I don't know, maybe you've done this before. I was hoping to solve this quickly but I suppose I'll just wait to see what Razer has to say, thanks anyway.

Comment: I have contacted Razer support and it took as long as it took